# Keyboard and Trackpad not working while installing windows 10 on MacBook Pro 2018 Touch Bar using Bootcamp

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, trackpad

I have tried several times to install Windows 10 on my new MBP 2018, and I have failed till now.

I used Windows ISO version 1703 which was ok until an error appeared at the end of setup (the error was:"windows could not update the computer's boot installation. installation cannot proceed").

Then I found an this [Problem Installing Boot Camp Windows Partition on new Mac Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123529/problem-installing-boot-camp-windows-partition-on-new-mac-pro). I followed the instructions according to this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337929/321893. Every thing went well until the Windows installer started. At that stage the trackpad and keyboard did not work, and I could not do anything. I had to force shutdown by pressing the power button.

Comment: Why did you choose to use an Windows ISO that is almost 2 years old? Why not use the current release 1809?

Comment: @DavidAnderson first I used version 1806, it did not go well. so I found that version 1703 works fine. That did not work for me, so I switched back to 1806. and followed the instruction said in the link above. every thing was fine except unresponsive trackpad and keyboard.

Comment: I have this exact same problem while trying to install a 2019 iso. Im guessing ill have to plug in a keyboard and mouse. Hoping someone can find a solution.